# Haskell limit number of recursions

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads

I want to create a monad which will prevent more than 10 instances of recursion (which I am implementing by preventing more than 10 instances of `>>=`). My `>>=` definition seems kind of long and messy though, so I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

I am including a factorial function which uses this monad as an example of how it could be used.

```
import Control.Monad.State
type LimitState a = (State Int (Either String a))
newtype Limiter a = Limiter {getState :: (LimitState a)}

instance Monad Limiter where
    return x = Limiter $ return $ Right x
    (Limiter state) >>= f = Limiter $ 
        do
            increment
            newCount <- get
            if newCount >= 10 
                then return $ Left "too many recursions"
                else getNextValue
        where 
            increment = do
                count <- get
                put (count + 1)
            getNextValue = do
                value <- state
                getState $ case value of
                    (Left message) -> Limiter $ return $ Left message
                    (Right v) -> f v

limitedFactorial :: Int -> Limiter Int
limitedFactorial 1 = return 1
limitedFactorial n = do
    recursive <- limitedFactorial (n - 1)
    return $ n * recursive

testLimitedFactorial =
    let (aValue, _) = runState (getState $ limitedFactorial 5) 0
        (uValue, _) = runState (getState $ limitedFactorial 11) 0
    in print aValue >> print uValue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *Sheriff voice:* Halt! You are breaking the laws!

Your monad breaks the right- and left-identity law of `>>=`:

```
k        >>= return = k   -- right identity
return a >>= f      = f a -- left  identity
```

Suddenly, it makes a *big* difference whether I call `return` at the end of my function:

```
do
   replicateM 9 actions        -- fine

do
   k <- replicateM 9 actions
   return k                     -- fails
```

That simply breaks to much. Your Monad is also missing its Functor and Applicative instances, which would make it easy to "cheat". And if you implemented a `fmap` that limits the number of `fmap`s, you start to break Functor laws. Note that due to the Monad/Functor laws, we should be able to rewrite

```
limitedFactorial :: Int -> Limiter Int
limitedFactorial 1 = return 1
limitedFactorial n = do
    recursive <- limitedFactorial (n - 1)
    return $ n * recursive
```

to

```
limitedFactorial :: Int -> Limiter Int
limitedFactorial 1 = return 1
limitedFactorial n = fmap (n *) $ limitedFactorial (n - 1)
```

If you were to limit that, you would break `fmap id = id` immediately.

But even without all of these quirks, at long last, there's nothing preventing the user to use recursion:

```
example :: Limit Int
example = return 1      -- fine

evil :: Int -> a -> Int
evil x _ = if x > 0 then 1 + evil (x - 1) undefined else 0

do
    liftM (evil 100000000) example -- recursion!
```

So conceptionally, your Monad is broken, unfortunately.

## Further review

1. Your code uses names from your imports. `state` is a function defined in `Control.Monad.State`, so it makes your instance slightly hard to read.
2. You use `increment` only once, so it makes sense to inline it.